# What kind of controls are used in the Windows Security Center?

Tags: windows, controls, uicomponents, securitycenter

Control Panel -> Security Center

I really like the components/controls which are used to show if a firewall or the Automatic Updates are enabled.
Are these reusable controls in C# or Delphi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These components are internal to Windows and are not available to be used outside of the operating system (and are written in C++).

Answer (score 0):

These are not reusable. They are built into Windows so you would need to either make your own custom version of these controls or find someone who already has if you want to mimic their look.

If you post a new question (or just  add to this one) asking how to make something like it, and state what language/environment you would like to do it in, I'm sure we could point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are reusable (of course, as they are in ring 3 !!!)
Simply load them from ATL.DLL (C code had been posted several years ago on BBS...)
Some wrong and newbie answers are unbelievable...